# Symfony2 ProxyPass breaks routing_dev settings

Tags: php, symfony, mod-proxy

I have a legacy php app and I ve set up a new vhost for a Symfony2 app.
I am using ProxyPass in Apache to point www.old-app.com/v2 to www.new-app.com.

It all work fine out of the box and the only problem is that the paths for the dev tools are broken. For example the dev toolbar does not load and because of that I get a prompt to open the profile but this opens in www.old-app.com/_profiler instead of www.old-app.com/v2/_profiler.
So that routing does not account for my ProxyPass. However in this case if I manually put v2 in the redirect address I get the profiler page.

If I add the prefix /v2/_profiler in the yml file it opens but I get
No route found for "GET /_profiler/f9784b".

So far my best solution is to add ProxyPass directives for the dev paths:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /v2 http://new-app
    ProxyPass /_wdt http://new-app/_wdt
    ProxyPass /_profiler http://new-app/_profiler
    ProxyPass /_configurator http://new-app/_configurator
    ProxyPass /_error http://new-app/_error

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /v2
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain new-app old-app

    ServerName old-app
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```